# Problems rendering main.js of Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to Vue and I need to maintain a project .. the problem is this: I have in main.js the route scheme ..

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
});
```

pages/page.vue

```
<span>{{ message }}</span>
```

It turns out that I'm trying to display the "message" that is on the date in an external template .. which is in the folder address "../pages/page.vue"; but when I put {{message}} I get the following error:

[Vue Warn]: Property or method "message" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

Thank you!

Comment: What would be the correct way to do the same?
And .. forgetting the part of the routes, I just need to display the {{message}} in the template, can you help me?

Comment: Which template?

Comment: I'm trying to display the "message" of date: {} .. in a template that is in the following folder address "../pages/page.vue"

Comment: Hello World! plus the error I listed above appears

Comment: How are you importing/using the `pages/page.vue` component?

Comment: Can you show the part where you actually render this template?

Comment: You should only use data binding within a single component. If you want data binding across different components you have to use props.

Comment: Is it necessary to import main.js into page.vue? how do I do that ?
This is the repository link .. https://github.com/wDrik/test-vue-project I need to use {{message}} in pages / segmentationMailingPf.vue

Answer (score 0):

You have already created a **Vue instance** that you can use across your project components.

[Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Creating-a-Vue-Instance) explain in really well:

> A Vue application consists of a root Vue instance created with new Vue, optionally organized into a tree of nested, reusable components.

The problem you have is that you are trying to access the data value directly from `main.js` to an outside component (`page.vue`). You should pass the data from your main.js through properties.

You may want to see the a working example, I have added line comments on the sandbox to guide you.

Please take a look to it

[image: Edit Vue Template]